# Cannot access to nginx docker container with custom server_name

Tags: docker, nginx

I have this simple nginx configuration and I can't access from my local machine:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/application
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    client_max_body_size 108M;
    server_name mydomain.dev;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;

    root /application;
    index index.php;
}
```

My /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.dev
```

Ping results:

```
ping mydomain.dev
PING mydomain.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.157 ms
```

In my browser **http://mydomain.dev** gets **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** but http://localhost works...

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you run your `nginx`?

Comment: Hi @Saeed i've just updated the post with my docker-compose.yaml thanks for your reply.

Comment: I dont know if this is still a thing but I have something in mind `.dev` will not work with chrome. Do you use chrome? Can you try another domain in `/etc/hosts` like example.com?

Comment: `.dev` domains work fine for me, can you see if your domain is being resolved properly? And what happens if you curl localhost?

Comment: I don't think there's need to do this in `/etc/hosts` file. What if you `exec` the `nginx` container and get its IP by command `docker exec -it nginx_name ip a`, then run for example `172.27.0.18` if that's your container's IP?

Comment: `curl localhost` works fine. `docker exec -it nginx_name ip a` says docker ip is: 172.19.0.3 but http://172.19.0.3 is not working.

Comment: When you `curl localhost` or even `wget -O index localhost`, then `cat index`, do you see the contents you should? I mean are the contents of file fine as they should be?

Comment: Yes. I get my website

Comment: I'm not sure whether the reason is that  the domain [mydomain.dev](https://mydomain.dev/)  exists on the internet, I change  `mydomain.dev`  to other domain like `customDomain.com`, and it works.

Comment: As @frank_lee said it may be due to some domain name. Change it and check again. I checked my nginx conf files and they're similar to yours

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

As some people said in comments I've changed to mydomain.org and it's working now.